# Unable to create a collection on Solr cloud

Tags: solr, solrj, solr4, solrcloud

I am unable to create a collection named 'testCollection' in the Solr Cloud.

**URL:** :8080/solr/admin/collections?action=CREATE&name=testCollection

**Response:** :

```
<str name="Operation create caused exception:">
org.apache.solr.common.SolrException:org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: No config set found to associate with the collection.
</str>
```

**As per the documentation:** (https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Collections+API#CollectionsAPI) for create collction API, `"collection.configName"` is not a mandatory field.  If not provided, Solr will default to the collection name as the configuration name.

Why am I still facing this issue?

Is collection.configName mandatory?

How do I find out the associated collection.configName on zookeeper?

Comment: What is the version of Solr?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must still upload the config set on to the zookeeper. You can find the list of config sets on the zookeeper in the admin UI under cloud->tree->configs. The collections are under cloud->tree->collections. If you click on a collection, you can find the config set that's associated with it: ({"configName":"MyConfig"})

You can upload the config set to the zookeeper using the zkcli.sh command on your solr host:

```
cd /opt/solr/server/scripts/cloud-scripts
./zkcli.sh -cmd upconfig -confdir /opt/solr/server/solr/MyCollection -confname MyConfig -z zoo1IP:2181,zoo2IP:2181,zoo3IP:2181
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer :)